# Progress Bar in Streamlit to Show Status of Download

Tags: python, streamlit

I am building a simple web app in streamlit and there are two download buttons on the page. I have tried using the function st.progress(), but the progress bar shows before clicking the download. I would like it to initialize the progress bar upon clicking the download button.

Attached is my code snippet:

```
st.download_button(
    label="Download Text",
    data=text,
    file_name='Sample.txt'
)

progress_text = "Operation in progress. Please wait."
my_bar = st.progress(0, text=progress_text)

for percent_complete in range(100):
    time.sleep(0.01)
    my_bar.progress(percent_complete + 1, text=progress_text)
time.sleep(1)
my_bar.empty()

st.button("Rerun")
```

Comment: In the first place, does your progress bar visualize the time of the download? Also, you can't start the button if you can't get the download completed, right?

Comment: @r-beginners It does not visualize the time of the download, and I would like it to start when the user clicks on the download button

Comment: `st.download_button` returns `True` when clicked.